# Não consigo diminuir o tamanho de componentes .form-control

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-3

Olá,

Eu estou tentando diminuir o tamanho de componentes que usam a classe .form-control do bootstrap 3 mas quando tento setar o width dos componentes para o valor "auto" ele gera uns espaçamentos entre os componentes que eu não consigo identificar analisando o código HTML.

Esse é o problema que eu quero resolver, diminuir o tamanho dos últimos 3 select's para "auto"

[image: Esse é o problema que eu quero resolver, diminuir o tamanho dos últimos 3 select's para "auto"]

Código HTML da interface acima:

```html
<div flex hide-sm hide-xs>
 <div class="input-group not-printable">
  <div class="input-group-addon" ng-click="search = ''"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-erase" ng-class="!!search === false ? 'text-color-black' : 'text-color-red'"></span></div>
  <input id="search" name="searchValue.$" type="text" class="form-control"/>
  <!-- <div class="input-group-addon" ng-click="search = ''"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-erase"></span></div> -->
  <span class="input-group-addon" style="width:0px; padding-left:0px; padding-right:0px; border:none;"></span>
  <select class="form-control">
   <option>2019</option>
   <option>2018</option>
   <option>2017</option>
   <option>2016</option>
   <option>2015</option>
  </select>
  <span class="input-group-addon" style="width:0px; padding-left:0px; padding-right:0px; border:none;"></span>
  <select class="form-control">
   <option>2019</option>
   <option>2018</option>
   <option>2017</option>
   <option>2016</option>
   <option>2015</option>
  </select>
  <span class="input-group-addon" style="width:0px; padding-left:0px; padding-right:0px; border:none;"></span>
  <select class="form-control">
   <option>Tudo</option>
   <option>Função</option>
   <option>Tipo de Sistema</option>
   <option>Sistema</option>
   <option>Veículo</option>
  </select>
 </div>
</div>
```

Mas quando tento setar o width para "auto" me acontece isso:

Os select's ficam separados por espaçamento que eu não consigo identificar analisando o código HTML.

[image: Os select's ficam separados por espaçamento que eu não consigo identificar analisando o código HTML.]

Código da interface acima:

```html
<div flex hide-sm hide-xs>
 <div class="input-group not-printable">
  <div class="input-group-addon" ng-click="search = ''"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-erase" ng-class="!!search === false ? 'text-color-black' : 'text-color-red'"></span></div>
  <input id="search" name="searchValue.$" type="text" class="form-control"/>
  <!-- <div class="input-group-addon" ng-click="search = ''"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-erase"></span></div> -->
  <span class="input-group-addon" style="width:0px; padding-left:0px; padding-right:0px; border:none;"></span>
  <select class="form-control" style="width: auto;">
   <option>2019</option>
   <option>2018</option>
   <option>2017</option>
   <option>2016</option>
   <option>2015</option>
  </select>
  <span class="input-group-addon" style="width:0px; padding-left:0px; padding-right:0px; border:none;"></span>
  <select class="form-control" style="width: auto;">
   <option>2019</option>
   <option>2018</option>
   <option>2017</option>
   <option>2016</option>
   <option>2015</option>
  </select>
  <span class="input-group-addon" style="width:0px; padding-left:0px; padding-right:0px; border:none;"></span>
  <select class="form-control" style="width: auto;">
   <option>Tudo</option>
   <option>Função</option>
   <option>Tipo de Sistema</option>
   <option>Sistema</option>
   <option>Veículo</option>
  </select>
 </div>
</div>
```

O que está gerando esse espaçamento entre os componentes?

PS: Estou usando Bootstrap 3 e AngularJS.

Answer (score 2):

Como vc está usando Bootstrap 3 uma das opções para corrigir isso é colocando `float:left` nos elementos do `form`. Mas depois disso vc vai precisar fazer o tratamento responsivo para ajusta-los quando a tela for pequena, se é que vc vai usar esse `form` em telas mobile por exemplo...

Segue o exemplo

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
         <div flex hide-sm hide-xs>
            <div class="input-group not-printable">
               <div class="input-group-addon" ng-click="search = ''"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-erase" ng-class="!!search === false ? 'text-color-black' : 'text-color-red'"></span></div>
               <input id="search" name="searchValue.$" type="text" class="form-control" style="width: auto; float: left;"/>
               <!-- <div class="input-group-addon" ng-click="search = ''"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-erase"></span></div> -->
               <span class="input-group-addon" style="width:0px; padding-left:0px; padding-right:0px; border:none; float: left;"></span>
               <select class="form-control" style="width: auto; float: left;">
                  <option>2019</option>
                  <option>2018</option>
                  <option>2017</option>
                  <option>2016</option>
                  <option>2015</option>
               </select>
               <span class="input-group-addon" style="width:0px; padding-left:0px; padding-right:0px; border:none; float: left;"></span>
               <select class="form-control" style="width: auto; float: left;">
                  <option>2019</option>
                  <option>2018</option>
                  <option>2017</option>
                  <option>2016</option>
                  <option>2015</option>
               </select>
               <span class="input-group-addon" style="width:0px; padding-left:0px; padding-right:0px; border:none; float: left;"></span>
               <select class="form-control" style="width: auto; float: left;">
                  <option>Tudo</option>
                  <option>Função</option>
                  <option>Tipo de Sistema</option>
                  <option>Sistema</option>
                  <option>Veículo</option>
               </select>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```